# Change two column's values when a pattern appears in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table such as:

```
seqnames start end  strand
1 scaffold_0 1 50 -
2 scaffold_0 30 120 +
3 scaffold_0 60 400 -
4 scaffold_0 100 300 +
```

And I juste wanted for each row, when there is the pattern "-" to replace the value between end and start.

So it should get:

```
seqnames start end  strand
1 scaffold_0 50 1 -
2 scaffold_0 30 120 +
3 scaffold_0 400 60 -
4 scaffold_0 100 300 +
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mask and call it under `df.loc[]` then assign the values in reverse:

```
l=df['strand'].eq("-")
df.loc[l,['start','end']] = df.loc[l,['end','start']].values
print(df)

     seqnames  start  end strand
1  scaffold_0     50    1      -
2  scaffold_0     30  120      +
3  scaffold_0    400   60      -
4  scaffold_0    100  300      +
```